# Issues Importing Variable/Classes for Main.js to use

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the NatoAlphabet into another javascript file to be used in the main javascript file. I am trying to make it so that in the future I can add more custom Phonetic Alphabets to choose from. However I am having issues using the variables from the other file.

Is there a way I can import the alphabet.js file for further use? I am also open to other approaches.

Thank you!

## Alphabet.js

```
var NatoAlphabet = {"a":"Alpha",
    "b":"Bravo", 
    "c":"Charlie", 
    "d":"Delta", 
    "e":"Echo", 
    "f":"Foxtrot", 
    "g":"Golf", 
    "h":"Hotel", 
    "i":"India", 
    "j":"Juliett", 
    "k":"Kilo", 
    "l":"Lima", 
    "m":"Mike", 
    "n":"November",
    "o":"Oscar", 
    "p":"Papa", 
    "q":"Quebec", 
    "r":"Romeo", 
    "s":"Siera", 
    "t":"Tango", 
    "u":"Uniform", 
    "v":"Victor",
    "w":"Wiskey", 
    "x":"X-ray", 
    "y":"Yankee", 
    "z":"Zulu"};
```

## Main.js

```
import {NatoAlphabet} from "alphabet.js";
    
var textToTranscribe = "";
var transcribedOutput = document.getElementById("transcribedOutput");
var arrayToTranscribe = [];


function transcribeOnClick(){
    transcribedOutput.innerHTML = ""
    textToTranscribe = document.getElementById("textToTranscribe").value; 
    convertStringToArray();
    arrayToTranscribe.forEach(transcribeChar)
}

function convertStringToArray(){
    arrayToTranscribe = Array.from(textToTranscribe);
    console.log(arrayToTranscribe);
}

function transcribeChar(index){
    if(index == " "){
        transcribedOutput.innerHTML += "<br>";
    }else{
        transcribedOutput.innerHTML += index.toUpperCase() + " as in " + "<b>" 
                                        + NatoAlphabet[index.toLowerCase()] + "</b>" +"<br>";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You will need to export `NatoAlphabet`. See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file/950146#950146

Answer (score 1):

The simple approach would be using ES6 modules  see  [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

1. First we include our main.js file in `index.html`  using script src ... but catch is in type value must be `module` to use import statements
2. Second create our `Alphabet.js` file and add an export keyword to the item which we want to import in other scripts. ( U can export as many as functions variables etc )
3. Finally we import our **NatoAlphabet** variable from `Alphabet.js` file using import statement.  **( here remember we need to provide the absolute or relative path to the file from which we are importing the js content )**.

Solution =>

**index.html**

```
 <!-- some above code -->
 <script src="main.js" type="module" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <!-- some below code -->
```

**Alphabet.js**

```
export let NatoAlphabet = {
  "a": "Alpha",
  "b": "Bravo",
  "c": "Charlie",
  "d": "Delta",
  "e": "Echo",
  "f": "Foxtrot",
  "g": "Golf",
  "h": "Hotel",
  "i": "India",
  "j": "Juliett",
  "k": "Kilo",
  "l": "Lima",
  "m": "Mike",
  "n": "November",
  "o": "Oscar",
  "p": "Papa",
  "q": "Quebec",
  "r": "Romeo",
  "s": "Siera",
  "t": "Tango",
  "u": "Uniform",
  "v": "Victor",
  "w": "Wiskey",
  "x": "X-ray",
  "y": "Yankee",
  "z": "Zulu"
};
```

**main.js**

```
import {NatoAlphabet} from "./Alphabet.js";   
console.log(NatoAlphabet)
//... All other code
```

> NOTE : All the files must be in same folder ( you can change the structure but remember to  update your import from location )

Comment: @confoundr Does this helps you  solve your problems ?

Comment: I receive the following error in the log when attempting to use the import. `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

Comment: @confoundr Are you getting this error in all browsers or a particular ? ( Please try to check it in all browsers first)

Comment: thank you. yes, this occurs in Chrome, and Firefox.